# pm2-runtime ignores my logging parameters

Tags: docker, pm2

I am running pm2-runtime version 5.3.0 inside a Docker container, to start a nodejs process.

I am trying to disable pm2's logging, as it is redundant with things I have elsewhere, except for the pm2 events themselves, which I want to track (restarts etc...)

I launch pm2-runtime as follows:

```
pm2-runtime start pm2.json --error /var/log/someFolder/pm2Error.log --output /dev/null --env production --only core-anon
```

My pm2.json includes the following line:

```
            "log_file": "/dev/null",
```

Despite that:

- /var/log/someFolder is empty
- I still have logs in the `.pm2/logs/` folder (`core-anon-error.log` and `core-anon-out.log`)

Am I getting this wrong? Thanks!